# Duplicate save in Django transaction causing InternalError instead of IntegrityError

Tags: django, transactions, django-views, django-orm

I am using PostgreSQL as my backend with psycopg2, and I'm noticing something that seems strange to me.  My set up is as follows:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()

class ChildModel(ParentModel):
    field2 = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

When I try to save a ChildModel object with a duplicate field2 from the shell, I get an InternalError instead of an IntegrityError, but *only* if the save is done in a transaction.commit_on_success block like so:

```
with transaction.commit_on_success():
    newObj = ChildModel(field1=5, field2=10) # Assume that a ChildModel with field2 == 10 exists
```

Outside of the transaction block, I get an IntegrityError, as I would expect.

When running inside view code, I always get the InternalError following the failed update even using savepoints:

```
try:
    sid = transaction.savepoint()
    newObj = ChildModel(field1=5, field2=10) # Assume that a ChildModel with field2 == 10 exists
    transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
except IntegrityError:
    transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
except InternalError:
    transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)

... other stuff ... # raises InternalError on next database hit
```

Same thing happens if I do it within a commit_on_success transaction with block, instead of using savepoints.  I have TransactionMiddleware installed and I am not running PostgreSQL in autocommit mode.

I can avoid the situation by simply checking to make sure the duplicate object doesn't exist, but I want to udnerstand what's going wrong with my understanding of Django transactions.  What gives?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. I looked at Postgres log files and could see that another query is being run after the query which caused the integrity error, which leads to actual error being eclipsed in default transaction settings. I found out that the extra query is coming from `django-debug-toolbar` app.

Google pointed me to https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/351 which seems to solve the problem.

In short, if you are using django-debug-toolbar<=0.9.4, disabling it solves the problem.

Comment: I haven't messed with this code in a while now, so I'm not really sure if this solves the problem above or not. But thanks for the head's up!